# POST Request only works on second time since server startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Every time I'm restarting up my server the data from the first post request does get saved in **var** proudctNum, but the whole **var** request = http.get function goes NAN until I post again.

What do I need to do?

```
//Global Vars
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.priceES = null
    res.locals.lowPrice = null
    res.locals.priceArray = null
    next()
  })
  //Set Static Path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('newpage') //change to index
})
var currencyGBP = ""

function getCurrency() {}
getCurrency()
var priceES = ""
var priceArray
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var proudctNum = req.body.product
  console.log("Product num is:.. " + proudctNum);
  priceArray = [{
    "ID": 0,
    "price": Math.round(priceES / currencyEUR),
    "country": "ES"
  }, {
    "ID": 6,
    "price": 10,
    "country": "TEST"
  }]
  var url = "API" + proudctNum + "&store=";
  //server rquest
  var request = http.get(url + "RU", function(res) {
    var body = ""
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    })
    res.on("end", function() {
      var profile = JSON.parse(body);
      priceRU = profile[0].productPrice.current.value;
      //console.log("Russia Price is:.." + priceRU);
    })

  });
  var lowPrice = priceArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.price < curr.price ? prev : curr;
  });
  //console.log(priceArray[0].price);
  console.log(lowPrice)

  function FINALRENDER() {
    console.log(priceArray)
    res.render('newpage', priceArray)
  }
  setTimeout(FINALRENDER, 5000)
})
```

html/ejs code

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="product" onfocus="this.value=''" value="TEXT" class="formInput">
    <p class="text-faded mb-5"><BR>TEXTEXT </p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="/" value="TEXT"></a>
```

Comment: Your POST endpoint is doing another HTTP call. Do you want that function to complete before returning a result to the user? if so, you need to move `res.end` to the callback function of `http.get`

Comment: where is that ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g2ue71xt/

Comment: I have multiple http.req it the function that i have deleted, i dont want to render the page on the 1st, only when all finished

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if your NodeJS and your JavaScript Methods are both POST? I had this problems a several times when i once wrote GET and on the other side POST ;)